# Compare CStringArray element?

Tags: c++, mfc

In this code `keepSelectedFiles` contain 5 text files. And `keepFiles` contain 3 text Files from `keepSelectedFiles`. I just want to compare this both array and after that remove 3 `keepFiles` from the `keepSelectedFiiles`. Then just 2 files left in `keepSelectedFiles`. This code is not working.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < keepSelectedFiles.GetSize(); i++)

{
    testbox4.AddString(keepSelectedFiles[i]);

    CString s1 = keepSelectedFiles[i];
    CString s2 = keepFiles[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < keepFiles.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        if (s1.Compare(s2) != 0)
        {
            junkFiles.Add(keepSelectedFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: If `s1` and `s2` are not equal then you have to add it to `junkfiles` array??

Comment: So i do what correct this code please?

Comment: You have posted several variations on this topic now, and most of them are pretty basic. I would advise you to study a programming book or online course. You are not going to improve your coding skills by asking Stack Overflow users to write and debug your code for you.

Comment: GazTheDestroyer if you think this is basic why you don't solve this problem. Maybe you are senior but in programming nothing is basic and nothing is advance. When it came to reality both is same.

Comment: @AlexCerry If you changed your container to `std::vector<CString>` instead of CStringArray, the solution is a 2 line loop.  In this day and age, there is little reason to be using MFC container classes such as CStringArray.

Comment: @AlexCerry Correction, it would be a `1 line loop:`  Example:  `for (int i = 0; i < keepFiles.GetSize(); i++)       keepSelectedFiles.erase(std::remove(keepSelectedFiles.begin(), keepSelectedFiles.end(), keepFiles[i]), keepSelectedFiles.end()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < keepSelectedFiles.GetSize(); i++)

{    
    bool flag = false;
    CString s1 = keepSelectedFiles[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < keepFiles.GetSize(); j++)// you can use different variable name
    {                                            //so there will be no confusion
        CString s2 = keepFiles[j];
        if (s1.Compare(s2) == 0)           // if s1 equal to s2
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
     }

        if(!flag){
               junkFiles.Add(keepSelectedFiles[i]); // or you can pass s1 here
               keepSelectedFile.RemoveAt(i); // remove index value
               i--;
         }
         else // first empty textbox4 before this loop
            testbox4.AddString(keepSelectedFiles[i]);  // update textbox  value             

}
```

Comment: Still code is not working junkFiles contain all Files.

Comment: Debug Assertion Failed?

Answer (score 0):

```
CString s2 = keepFiles[i];
```

move the above line and put this line in the inner for loop.

Comment: Still code is not working junkFiles contain all Files.

Comment: try to print both the value before the compare statement and you will get to know what the two values are getting compaired.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 for loops:

```
for (int i = 0,  j=0; i < keepSelectedFiles.GetSize(); i++)

{    
    CString s1 = keepSelectedFiles[i];
    CString s2 = keepFiles[j];
    if (s1.Compare(s2) != 0)
    {
                junkFiles.Add(keepSelectedFiles[i]);
     }
     else
     {
           ++j;
           testbox4.AddString(keepSelectedFiles[i]);
     }
 }
```